# Stash the difference between current branch and master to apply it to an old commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-extensions

how can I stash the difference between current branch and master to apply it to an old commit, in other words I should apply a new feature in current version(Master) and old version(old Master commit 1 year ago).

Comment: You really don't want to change an old commit like that. Every commit after it would need to be rebased on top of the new changes. Instead create a new branch at the old commit and merge the changes into that branch and then make a new release from that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to apply a new feature to any branch on your master:

1.Cherry-pick all commits one by one using

```
git cherry-pick hash_of_commit
```

But it will take some time to do if you have a lot of commits.

2. Squash your commits you would like to apply into one commit and then cherry-pick this one (already squashed commit) to any branch you would like to.

To squash you can use `git rebase -i hash_of_the_commit` - this command would do an interactive rebase to `hash_of_the_commit`, which should be one commit before you started developing feature. Then in interactive mode you mark all commits to squash. Might lead to conflicts while squashing.

3.Create patch

```
git diff from-commit to-commit > output-file
```

and then apply patch to your other branch:

```
git apply output-file
```

Comment: Thank you Anastasiia for your answer , I will later try the third one , if it works I will mark your answer as the right one, I have no permission to do rebase at work :)

Comment: You don't need permissions to rebase on your fork.